# Kindle with iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to buy a Kindle and use my iPhone 3G to connect to the internet to download books.  Do I need to buy the Kindle 3G + Wifi to work?  Another thing, will the two work together?

Comment: Do you have wifi at home?

Comment: No I do not have wifi at home?

Comment: Then I recommend strongly that you buy the Kindle with built in 3G.

Answer (score 3):

Personal Hotspot only works on iPhone 4 or above. Note that many networks will charge you extra to use it though.

The Kindle 3G has free internet downloads internationally, so I'd probably recommend that over upgrading your phone.

Having said that, I own a Kindle (wifi only) and I happily download all my books at home (via wifi). Only once have I actually connected it to my iPhone 4 hotspot!

Answer (score 2):

From the way you phrase your question, I think you lack a basic understanding of how the Kindle bookstore system works. Forgive me if any of the following is something you may already know.

With Amazon Kindle, you can purchase books from Amazon through a web browser on any platform--a computer, an iPhone or iPod or iPad, or any other kind of device that connects to the Internet.

You can then take the books that you bought from Amazon and load them onto your Kindle through any of several different methods. You can download the book to your computer, connect your Kindle to the computer via a USB cable, and then upload the book to the Kindle over the cable. Another method is to have a Kindle that connects to WiFi or to the cell phone network, and to connect to the Amazon bookstore that way, to make purchases and to download any purchases that you have made.

Furthermore, there are Kindle apps for Mac OS X, Windows, iPhone and iPad and other applications, and if you purchase a digital book in Kindle format from Amazon, you can read the same book on any and all of these devices including the Kindle itself. Whenever you connect to Amazon.com by any of these various methods, all the books you have purchased are available to be downloaded and read on any of them.

Comment: Yes I am knew to Kindle and really appreciate your feedback. It was very helpful. Thanks.  Then I need to buy the Wifi only.  I do not need the 3G + Wifi?

Comment: Yes, you can save money by not buying the 3G version if you are OK with downloading new books to your regular computer and then uploading them to the Kindle over USB, or if you can connect your Kindle to a WiFi signal anywhere.

Comment: De rien, mon ami.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your iPhone's [mobile hotspot feature](http://www.macworld.com/article/158556/2011/03/personal_hotspot_att.html) to create a portable Wifi network to which your kindle can connect to using wifi. I should note that the kindle's data is free once you buy the 3G device, yet the iPhone's data is subject to your carrier's fury.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your iPhone to a newer model, a wifi-only kindle can be attached to the iPhone's 3G connection using the mobile hotspot feature. I could be wrong, but I don't think mobile hotspot works on an iPhone 3G.

I'm not suggesting you buy a new iPhone now, but keep it in mind as something you'll probably do at some point in the future. Also note that some carriers will charge you extra for the hotspot feature (it's free with my carrier).

Any book you read on one can be read on the other (download the kindle app on your iPhone), and as far as I know it will keep your reading position in sync between them.

I would only spend extra money on the 3G kindle if you really need to be able to buy books while on the road, especially since you can always buy them on the iPhone instead if there's no wifi available, and download to the kindle once you have wifi.